# Calculate percentage of HIV cases in different US States using R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, data-wrangling

I have a dataset which contains the absolute number of HIV cases in four US states over a period of 2 years.

In my dataset, there are three columns `date` (Jan 2018, Feb 2018 ...) , `state` (CA, NY, FL, MA) , and `abs_cases`. I am ignoring changes in population over time. I now want to calculate the relative number of cases for each state using the population. Here are some example population data

`pop<- c("CA"= 11111, "NY"= 22222, "FL"= 33333,"MA"= 444444`).

I already tried using

```
df%>%
group_by(state)%>%
summarize(rel_cases= state/pop)
```

But it divides each state multiple times with a different population.
How can I divide only those values from e.g `FL` by the population of Florida and so on?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to merge the population data and the case data beforehand.

```r
library(dplyr)

# Case data
df = data.frame(
  state = c("A","B","C"),
  time = c(1,2,3),
  cases = rnorm(n = 9, mean = 100, sd = 50)
)

# Population data
pop = data.frame(
  state = c("A","B","C"),
  population = c(1000, 2000, 1500)
)

# We can use left_join to merge the two
df %>% 
  left_join(pop)
#> Joining, by = "state"
#>   state time     cases population
#> 1     A    1 120.58345       1000
#> 2     B    2 142.00035       2000
#> 3     C    3  94.35658       1500
#> 4     A    1  86.91845       1000
#> 5     B    2 222.63554       2000
#> 6     C    3 107.99530       1500
#> 7     A    1 144.48939       1000
#> 8     B    2 178.82640       2000
#> 9     C    3 149.46918       1500

# Finally make our summary
df %>% 
  left_join(pop) %>% 
  group_by(state, time) %>% 
  summarise(rel_cases = cases / population)
#> Joining, by = "state"
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'state', 'time'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#> # Groups:   state, time [3]
#>   state  time rel_cases
#>   <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 A         1    0.121 
#> 2 A         1    0.0869
#> 3 A         1    0.144 
#> 4 B         2    0.0710
#> 5 B         2    0.111 
#> 6 B         2    0.0894
#> 7 C         3    0.0629
#> 8 C         3    0.0720
#> 9 C         3    0.0996
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I am sorry that I did not provider unable code. Thank you so much @mhovd

Answer (score 0):

Without an example dataset, here is my guess at what you are trying to do. You can convert `pop` into a dataframe using `enframe` and join it to `df` by `state`. Then, you can compute the cases per population by each State in each month.

```
library(tidyverse)

pop <- c("CA"= 11111, "NY"= 22222, "FL"= 33333,"MA"= 444444)
pop <- enframe(pop, "state", "pop_num")

df %>%
  left_join(pop, by = "state") %>%
  mutate(rel_cases = abs_cases/pop_num)
```